# Date formatter returns nil for June

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a strange problem with those lines of code :

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMyyyy"];
NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:@"062008"];
NSLog(@"Date %@", date);
```

The result is :

```
 Date (null)
```

But when I change the month like this :

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMyyyy"];
NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:@"072008"];
NSLog(@"Date %@", date);
```

The result is :

```
Date 2008-06-30 23:00:00 +0000
```

For only the month of June (06), the date conversion from string fails !

I think, it's something related to timezone, any ideas.

Thanks

solved :

```
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

As I thought, it's related to timezone.

Comment: Write your own answer and click it answered -- it'll get you points and makes it clearer for others who follow.

Comment: And in your answer, you could explain in more detail: How is it related to time zone? OK, changing the time zone to GMT “fixed” it, but did it *really* fix it? What was the problem? If that is truly a fix and not just a bandage, then how does it solve the problem?

Comment: By the way: What time zone are *you* in? When I run that code, and apparently when hussain Shabbir (from the answers) runs it, we both get a date for `@"062008"`. You don't, so what time zone and calendar is your formatter using? If you left it at the defaults, what time zone and calendar is your system set to?

Comment: My timezone is : Africa/Casablanca

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks for the proposition, it's very nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved :
As I thought, it's related to timezone.

```
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations, you've found more timezone oddities!  You're correct that changing your time zone will fix the issue.  Let's go spelunking and see if we can figure out why!

First, we'll try and find every timezone where this weirdness happens:

```
NSArray *tzs = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
f.dateFormat = @"MMyyyy";
for (NSString *name in tzs) {
    f.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name];
    NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"062008"];
    if (date == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", name);
    }
}
```

This is going to loop through all known timezones and try to parse "062008" in that time zone.  If we run this, we find that it logs:

```
Africa/Casablanca
Asia/Karachi
```

So I'm guessing that you live in either Casablanca or Karachi (because by default, your `NSDateFormatter` is initialized with *your* timezone, which is why you're seeing this problem; probably Casablanca, given that you appear to be 1 hour ahead of GMT).

Let's see if we can figure out what's weird with those timezones:

```
$ zdump -v Africa/Casablanca
... snip ...
Africa/Casablanca  Sun Jun  1 00:00:00 2008 UTC = Sun Jun  1 01:00:00 2008 WEST isdst=1
... snip ...

$ zdump -v Asia/Karachi
... snip ...
Asia/Karachi  Sat May 31 19:00:00 2008 UTC = Sun Jun  1 01:00:00 2008 PKST isdst=1
... snip ...
```

Sure enough, it looks like both Casablanca and Karachi skipped the midnight hour on June 1st in 2008.  Thus, you're essentially giving it an unparse-able date, and it's returning `nil`.  In a nutshell.

In this case, the correct answer *is* to change your timezone (GMT is probably a great choice), because chances are this string you're parsing is not coming from user input (given its weird format), and thus should be parsed according to a standard timezone.  And although I'm sure that Casablanca and Karachi are really neat places, their timezones aren't exactly common ones...

## TL;DR:

Daylight Saving Time ought to be abolished.

Answer (score 1):

yes! you are absolutely correct. I am also faced same problem As my thought also, it's related to timezone.Not sure whether this is the ideal solution for your question

```
NSString *strDate=@"06-2008";
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM-yyyy"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:strDate];
NSLog(@"Date %@", date);
```

Comment: Changing the format the dates are written in isn't always an option, and doesn't reveal anything about what caused NSDateFormatter to return `nil` for that date in that format.