# How to group NSMutableArray by Date

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, sections

I have an NSMutableArray named records which contains some single records. So the structure is like:

- Records

  - Record ("name" : "test1", "timestamp" : "2013-09-15 12:34:35 +0000")
  - Record ("name" : "test2", "timestamp" : "2013-09-14 11:21:42 +0000")
  - Record ("name" : "test3", "timestamp" : "2013-09-14 10:47:42 +0000")
  - Record ("name" : "test4", "timestamp" : "2013-09-12 17:11:42 +0000")
  - Record ("name" : "test5", "timestamp" : "2013-09-12 19:52:42 +0000")

Know I want to display them all in a UITableView. That works fine without Sections:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [...]

    NSManagedObject *record = [self.records objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.recordNameLabel.text = [record valueForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}
```

But now I want to separate the records in sections by the timestamp value. So my idea is to create a new NSMutableArray named sorted Records with the following structure:

- Records

  - Day (2013-09-15)

    - Record ("name" : "test1", "timestamp" : "2013-09-15 12:34:35 +0000")
  - Day (2013-09-14)

    - Record ("name" : "test2", "timestamp" : "2013-09-14 11:21:42 +0000")
    - Record ("name" : "test3", "timestamp" : "2013-09-14 10:47:42 +0000")
  - Day (2013-09-12)

    - Record ("name" : "test4", "timestamp" : "2013-09-12 17:11:42 +0000")
    - Record ("name" : "test5", "timestamp" : "2013-09-12 19:52:42 +0000")

How can I group/separate the Records to my sorted-structure?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are your timestamps strings or NSDate objects?

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions is:

1) Create NSDate category with will have one method, for example day:

```
@interface NSDate(Day)
- (NSDate*) day;
@end
@implementation NSDate(Day)
- (NSDate*) day
{
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:self];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
}
@end
```

2) Use [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with sectionNameKeyPath - `@"timestamp.day"`.

Comment: +1, although I would highly recommend doing `comps.hour = 12;`.  That way the resulting `NSDate` will be at noon, and not midnight.  There are some weird things with midnight (not every day has a midnight) that can lead to subtly wrong results.

Comment: Dave, could you please explain what day does not have midnight? I have never seen such cases before.

Comment: In Brazil, the DST jumps happen at midnight, so on those days (when they lose an hour), there is no midnight.  The time goes directly from 11:59:59 PM to 1:00:00 AM.  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18663407/115730).

Answer (score 0):

If "Records" is a NSMutableArray of dictionary objects with a field "timestamp" of NSDate type, you may use NSSortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:FALSE];
[allVideos sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

*its a descending ordered array. `ascending:TRUE` indicate ascending order of an array!!!